A SF novel where a character steals an adhesive anti-slip mat in shape of a daisy from the bathroom of her host's house
This novel I read rather recently, during the early "Covid" years. But I don't remember much.
One thing I am positive about is that, in this universe, one can upload the mind of people (usually, just  when death is imminent) into a giant computer in which they keep "living". But contrary to the case of, for instance, John Varley's universe, one cannot download them back into clones in the "external" world. They can only continue to "live" in the computer.
Only one specific episode remains in my memory. One of the main characters, a young woman, is given access (from the outside !) to the computer. (IIRC, at some point later in the book, she will die and end up in the computer). She is told to choose a long password that she can easily remember but that nobody can guess. So she took the acronym of a rather long sentence. I cannot quote it verbatim, but I am probably very close. Something like :  I S(tole) A(n) A(dhesive) A(nti-slip) D(uck... Hmmm... an adhesive duck is mentioned the Big Bang Theory; here it was probably something else, maybe an adhesive flower) F(rom) T(he) B(athroom) O(f) M(r) W(hatever the name was)'s M(ansion). She can remember it because she actually did it, as a joke, or to keep a souvenir. But nobody saw her and could ever imagine she would choose such an acronym as password.

Memory works strangely. Something came back : the anti-slip mat was not a duck, but a flower, a daisy.
Also I am now positive that she died and was uploaded. All uploaded people took a different name when in the computer. And she chose to be called Daisy.
I don't remember the name she had when living. IIRC it started with a D, but I am not at all certain.
I followed Astrid Redfern's advice and went to TV Tropes: Brain Uploading and opened the "Literature" sub-file. It is extremely long, a lot of the entries are "spoilers", opening them all would be too long. I used the search engine for "daisy" and got no result. And the topic is of course the same for all entries, a superficial glance does not help.

I wonder if this is one of Pohl's Heechee books, which do have uploading to computers (called "vastening").  It would probably be "Mr. Broadhead's mansion" since he got very rich.

@Andrew  "one of Pohl's Heechee books".. could you be more specific ? I don't know anything about that series.

The Heechee series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heechee_Saga starting with Gateway.  If it doesn't ring a bell then I'm wrong :)

Any idea when it could have been from? Was it fairly new at the time of reading?

@Andrew  The titles don't ring a bell, but without any idea of the content, that does not prove much.

@Jenayah I think it was rather recent when I read it, but I really cannot be sure.

The Gateway series involves an alien base found on Venus, complete with spaceships programmed to automatically go to certain locations in space (FTL) and return. Humans risk their lives going out on these ships, and find valuable and dangerous things. In the later books, the ability to upload humans to computers is discovered - which is what reminded me of your question

@Andrew  I am not sure the action was on Earth, the whole novel might have taken place somewhere else. But I do not remember space travel playing an important place.

Thanks.  I'm probably on the wrong track then

Does anything at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BrainUploading sound familiar?

@Astrid_Redfern Well, there are dozens of entries. I'm not going to open them all to check against my memories of a single scene....

This is Neal Stephenson's Fall; or, Dodge in Hell from 2019
Dodge, the wealthy inventor of a popular MMORPG, dies unexpectedly and is the first person to have his brain frozen and uploaded into a developing world, so he becomes a god-like figure as he is reborn and starts creating the world. His grand-niece Sophia is a researcher with sole administrator access to the new digital world, and uses the daisy as part of her password.

Sophia nodded, feeling her face get slightly warm, as she had in fact
been thinking of names from D’Aulaires’ as suitable passwords. Instead
she typed in “IsasdftFffiI13da!,” for “I stole a shower daisy from the
Forthrast family farmhouse in Iowa 13 days ago!” As she did so, Uncle
C demurely looked away. The app asked her to reenter the password just
to make sure, and she did. Then she slid the tablet back across the
table, maneuvering it carefully between coffee cups and cream
pitchers. “Done,” she said.

Sophia was close to Dodge, and she took the daisy from his house during the funeral so that she would always have something, albeit small, that connected them. She attached it to her purse, so it became an ever-present personal totem. Dodge's brain was scanned in a destructive process and created tons of data that there was no precedent for understanding, so Sophia makes it the subject of her research as an undergrad. When she is first setting up the digital environment she uses the incident of taking the daisy as part of her password, and even after that research project eventually becomes something huge that the whole world is invested in her password retains significance as the key to her root priveleges. She eventually uses it to help free Dodge from imprisonment in the digital world.
The first parts are mostly a speculative sci-fi about what the real world becomes when we know there is a real afterlife that we can watch and prepare for, and the latter parts are a strange fantasy quest set in the digital world that didn't work for everyone, but I thought it had lots of great ideas.
It's a sequel to Reamde, which I highly recommend if you haven't read it yet.


Reamde was much better.  I have them both sitting on my shelf, and I've re-read Reamde, but have no such impulse towards Fall.

I guess I liked it more than most since I recognized it off of the question title instantly, but it's definitely low on my list of Stephenson's work to reread. Reamde is one that I've given as gifts.

I agree with DavidW. I liked Reamde very much, but not so much Fall. Hence I only remembered the theft of the daisy and the password. I cannot yet grant the bounty but I will as soon as the system lets me.
